# WCAT 6.1 for WCF DataService

Tags: wcf-data-services, wcat

I am using WCAT 6.1 for WCF DataService.
Is it possible to insert breakpoint in my code while executing WCAT script?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it myself, but I can imagine that debugging your WCF DataService while executing a WCAT script is no different than debugging it manually by [accessing the DataService from a web browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728279%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The key to making it work is that you will need to configure your WCAT scenario to make requests to a URI that resolves to the computer on which your DataService is running and VS.NET is installed.

Let's say that your DataService is hosted at `http://localhost:12345/northwind.svc`

Then you would set up your scenario to have a request that looked like this:

```
scenario
{
    transaction                        
    {                                  
        id = "Debug WCF DataService";
        weight = 10;

        request
        {
          verb = GET;
          url = "http://localhost:12345/northwind.svc";
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!